# Angular2 doesnot support nested properties in form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Any way to support nested fields in Angular2.

**Class**

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.form = this._fb.group({

  name: {
    given: ['', Validators.required],
    middle: [''],
    family: ['', Validators.required]
  }

 });
}
```

**Template**

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">

<input ngControl="name.given" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
<input ngControl="name.middle" type="text" placeholder="Middle Name">
<input ngControl="name.family" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">

</form>
```

I'm getting following `Cannot find control 'name.given'` error output in console. I've tried some other syntax `name['given']`, `name[given]` etc against `ngControl` but getting the same kind of error.

**How do you work with nested fields in angular2 ?**

Comment: And [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/FormBuilder-class.html) is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fix inline form (with `ngControl`) and programmatic form with `FormBuilder` - in this case, you need to use `ngFormControl`).

I think that you're looking for form groups. Here is a sample:

```
<div ngControlGroup="name" #cgName="ngForm">
  <p>First: <input ngControl="give" required></p>
  <p>Middle: <input ngControl="middle"></p>
  <p>Last: <input ngControl="family" required></p>
</div>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/M4FGTNAx8lo8jzBivH0P?p=preview.

Comment: Now I am getting `Cannot find control 'name -> given'` error message in console.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the `form` element. I added a plunkr in my answer ;-)

Comment: Its not working with [ngFormModel] [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/YZwO4PXwvqnMsAfsJ6oY?p=preview)

Comment: Yes it's normal because you can't mix inline forms with ones defined with `FormBuilder`... Note that you can define groups with `FormBuilder` as well. Here is a sample: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/FormBuilder-class.html.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, can you update your answer to rc5 requirements?